# Table prefix configuration in Phalcon Model

Tags: php, phalcon

I would like to set up a table prefix for all my models, since this is how it is designed in the database.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `getSource` method to set the prefix:

```
class Users extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'my_' . 'users';
    }
}
```

Or, you can set a base model class to set the table prefix for all models:

```
class BaseModel extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'my_' . strtolower(get_class($this));
    }
}
```

and extend all models from that

```
class Users extends BaseModel
{

}
```

or in PHP 5.4 you can create a trait:

```
trait CustomPrefix
{
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'my_' . strtolower(get_class($this));
    }
}
```

then in your model:

```
class Users extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    use CustomPrefix;
}
```

[Source](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/405/some-question-about-database)

Comment: I liked the idea of overriding getSource to add the table prefix, however may i suggest using this: `public function getSource() { return 'my_' . parent::getSource(); }` putting the model name as a string would be annoying for renaming models.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have tables with underscores "_" you could write it like that:

```
public function getSource()
{
    return 'my_'.strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', get_class($this)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also add all your settings to initialize function. If you have any connection between models like one-one many-many one-many you will define them also in initialize method.

```
class Robots extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource("the_robots");
    }

}
```